# What are the alternatives/solutions to a common minimization code for a batch file, that doesn't seem to be working for me

Tags: batch-file

I've got this code

```
if not DEFINED IS_MINIMIZED set IS_MINIMIZED=1 && start "" /min "%~dpnx0" %* && exit

taskkill /f /IM notepad2.exe
timeout /t 1
start /min "" "C:\Users\Leon\Dropbox\Light software\Notepad2.exe" "C:\Users\Leon\Dropbox\Backups\Notepad offset\1.txt"
start /min "" "C:\Users\Leon\Dropbox\Light software\Notepad2.exe" "C:\Users\Leon\Dropbox\Backups\Notepad offset\2.txt"
start /min "" "C:\Users\Leon\Dropbox\Light software\Notepad2.exe" "C:\Users\Leon\Dropbox\Backups\Notepad offset\3.txt"
start /min "" "C:\Users\Leon\Dropbox\Light software\Notepad2.exe" "C:\Users\Leon\Dropbox\Backups\Notepad offset\4.txt"
start /min "" "C:\Users\Leon\Dropbox\Light software\Notepad2.exe" "C:\Users\Leon\Dropbox\Backups\Notepad offset\5.txt"

exit
```

Where

```
if not DEFINED IS_MINIMIZED set IS_MINIMIZED=1 && start "" /min "%~dpnx0" %* && exit
```

Is supposed to minimize the CMD that opens after initiation, however, it simply doesn't get minimized. What could be the problem here?

If anything, what would be the currently, most quickest solution for running all batch files minimized? So far, I think that it might simply be creating a shortcut ➔ setting it to being minimized. But perhaps there are even better ways? Some sort of a global thing would sure be awesome

**IMPORTANT EDIT:**
I've just realized that the batch on itself works fine, however, I only use it in combination with opening of some other program, under the management of a program called FastKeys. Which looks like this

```
Run, C:\Users\Leon\Dropbox\Light software\Skype - Shortcut.lnk
Send, {500}
Run, C:\Users\Leon\Dropbox\Offset restart 1.bat
```

So yeah... on its' own it runs fine, but when something else is put along with it, it just doesn't get minimized at all...

Comment: When you `Set "IS_MINIMIZED=1"`, it is set only in the existing `cmd.exe` session. As soon as you open the new `cmd.exe` session, that variable is no longer defined!

Comment: Well, I cannot reproduce the problem, it works fine for me (I have to admint that I removed all lines that contain `Notepad2.exe`, but I guess that should not affect the minimisation)...

Comment: @Compo, `start` copies the current environment, hence environment variables and current working directory, so `IS_MINIMIZED` is available in the minimized instance; just place `echo %IS_MINIMIZED%` and `pause` before the final `exit` command...

Comment: @aschipfl, I don't have a Windows computer, so having an opportunity to check or test is impossible. I'm more than happy to accept your experience, although I'd still suggest using `If Not Defined IS_MINIMIZED Set "IS_MINIMIZED=1" & Start "" /Min "%~f0" %* & Exit`, as I see no purpose in using conditional statements here, just a logical sequence.

Comment: Wow, @Compo, how can you provide so many good CMD/Batch answers then? ;-) Anyway, I totally agree, `&` is sufficient here...

Comment: @aschipfl, well I had a PC a few years ago, and TBF things have changed little since then. _Sometimes I may have the opportunity to try things out on units in for repair_.

Comment: We would be drawn to the conclusion then, that `IS_MINIMIZED` has been set to some value in the master environment, hence `regedit` could be used to delete that setting.

Comment: @Compo Forgot/didn't realize to include one very important detail... added it into the thread under "IMPORTANT EDIT" 

Comment: @Magoo same as the post above...

Comment: @aschipfl same as the post above...